# How to convert table values of sql red by using Ado.net to json and display in jqgrid

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid-asp.net

I have written a piece of code using ado.net the main intention of the code retrieve the data from sql table and display results in html table. I was successful in doing this task. My question is how can I convert red values to jsondata and pass to view to display in JQGrid? I have googled regarding this but I am getting only Entity framework related stuff. Please help

Thanks in advance.

```
public ActionResult Details1()
{
    string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeContext"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    List<Employee> l = new List<Employee>();
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=Srivatsava; integrated security=SSPI"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Employee", connection);
        da.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
           l.Add(new Employee() { ID = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()), FirstName = dr[1].ToString(), LastName = dr[2].ToString(), Salary = int.Parse(dr[3].ToString()),Gender=dr[4].ToString() });
        }

        //Create an instance of SqlCommand class, specifying the T-SQL command that 
        //we want to execute, and the connection object.
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Id,FirstName,LastName,Salary,Gender from tblEm", connection);
        //rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        /*while (rdr.Read())
        {
            // get the results of each column
            int id = (int)rdr["ID"];
            string contact = (string)rdr["FirstName"];
            string company = (string)rdr["LastName"];
            int city = (int)rdr["Salary"];
            string gender = (string)rdr["Gender"];
            // print out the results
            Console.Write(contact);
            Console.Write(city);
            Console.Write(company);
            Console.WriteLine(gender);
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }*/
        connection.Close();
    }
    return View(l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `json` you should return `Json()` like following.

```
return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

instead of

```
return View(l)
```

Comment: var jsonData=new{ total=totalPages, page, records=totalRecords, rows=todoListResults }, return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);

Comment: Shall I have to format the data that we are passing to view like this?

Comment: If you want server side paging then you should format like this.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Action return type with JsonRrsult like below

```
public JsonResult Details1()
{
```

and return

```
return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

in your HTMLs update Jqgrid usage like below pointing url to your Controller/Action

```
$("#yourgrid").jqGrid({

          datatype: 'json',
          url: 'controller/action',
```

That should work.

Comment: var jsonData=new{

total=totalPages,
page,
records=totalRecords,
rows=todoListResults
},
return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);

Comment: Shall I have to convert the data that we are passing to view like this?

Comment: @rao Yes you need construct json in the format the jsgrid is expecting.